# Selecting cells from a Grid

Tags: jquery, grid

I have a DIV based grid, and I'd like users to select a single or multiple cells from it and do certain tasks.

Here's the grid: http://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/be0d10mL/3/

And here's how I get the Row and Cell position:

```
$(function() {
    $('.cell').click(function (event) {
        var rowID = $(this).parent().attr('class');
        rowID = rowID.match(/\d+/);
        var cellID = $(this).index();
        alert( "Row: " + rowID + " Cell: " + cellID );
    });
});
```

But how do I make it draggable so multiple blocks can be selected and get the position of the first (top-left) and the last (bottom-right)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, its much easier with jQuery [Selectable](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid):

```
$(".table").selectable({
    filter:".cell",
    stop: function() {
        var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
        $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
          var index = $( ".cell" ).index( this );
          result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
        });
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 3):

See http://jsfiddle.net/be0d10mL/4/

Use mousedown and mouseup events

```
var top, left, bottom, right;

$('.cell').on("mousedown", function (event) {
    var rowID = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    rowID = rowID.match(/\d+/);
    var cellID = $(this).index();
    top = rowID;
    left = cellID;
});


$('.cell').on("mouseup", function (event) {
    var rowID = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    rowID = rowID.match(/\d+/);
    var cellID = $(this).index();
    bottom = rowID;
    right = cellID;

    console.log("top: " + top + " left: " + left + " bottom: " + bottom + " right: " + right);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I found jquery Selectable which is much easier and user friendly. Thanks anyway!